# What is the scala way of looping over a function with different types

Tags: scala, functional-programming

New to scala. I've written a piece of code that does what its supposed to do. But i feel there is probably a more scala way of doing this.

```
def checkFunc(a: A, b: B, c: C): Boolean = {
  a.exists(c.types) && c.contains(b.id)
}

def runner(a: A, b: B): Boolean = {
 // do something
 // if (..) { .... }
 else {
   (checkFunc(a, b, c1) ||
    checkFunc(a, b, c2) ||
    checkFunc(a, b, c3) ||
    checkFunc(a, b, c4))
 }
}
```

I need to run the same check function with different objects of C type. Param A and Param B are the same on all the check function invocations.

Answer (score 2):

Probably

```
List(c1, c2, c3, c4).map(checkFunc(a, b, _)).reduce(_ || _)
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/collections-methods.html

This can be shortened using `exists` (courtesy of **@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez**)

```
List(c1, c2, c3, c4).exists(checkFunc(a, b, _))
```

Comment: I would use `exists` rather than `map` + `reduce`